# How to insert query in NodeJS with variables

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a query, but I am not sure how to allow NodeJS to input it with variables.. how do I achieve this? What is the best way?

```
var sql = (
    "INSERT INTO stats_tmp (
        id, 
        timestamp, 
        campaign_nm, 
        calls, 
        seconds, 
        answered, 
        failure, 
        dnc, 
        amd, 
        transfers, 
        transfer_seconds, 
        cost
    ) VALUES (" 
        + estarr[0].id + ", " 
        + estarr[0].timestamp + ", " 
        + estarr[0].name + ", " 
        + estarr[1].calls + ", " 
        + estarr[1].seconds + ", " 
        + estarr[1].answers + ", " 
        + estarr[1].failures + ", " 
        + estarr[1].dncs + ", " 
        + estarr[1].amd + ", " 
        + estarr[1].transfers + ", " 
        + estarr[1].transfers + ", " 
        + estarr[1].transferseconds + ", "
        + estarr[1].cost 
    + ")"
);
```

Comment: Do not concatenate to create queries, please use prepared statements https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries (or the equivalent in the lib you are using)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values
@Seblor
can you give me an example? I read it, but I kind of don't understand

Comment: This is the same module (just under a different name in NPM). Use prepared statements, as they are safer than simply escaping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use prepared statements.

Consider:

```
var query = connection.query(
    'INSERT INTO stats_tmp (
        id, 
        timestamp, 
        campaign_nm, 
        calls, 
        seconds, 
        answered, 
        failure, 
        dnc, 
        amd, 
        transfers, 
        transfer_seconds, 
        cost
    ) VALUES (
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?
    )',
    [
        estarr[0].id,
        estarr[0].timestamp,
        estarr[0].name,
        estarr[1].calls,
        estarr[1].seconds,
        estarr[1].answers,
        estarr[1].failures,
        estarr[1].dncs,
        estarr[1].amd,
        estarr[1].transfers,
        estarr[1].transfers,
        estarr[1].transferseconds,
        estarr[1].cost
    ],
    function(err, results) {    
      ...
});
```